# jQuery Button Removal

Tags: jquery, html, button, event-listener

I am trying to set up a form with dynamic number of fields, controlled with simple +/- jquery buttons.

I have assigned a class for the remove button, it is working as i hoped and can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cmaTG/

My problem is that whenever the user clicks on one of the remove buttons, not only do i want to remove that row from my table, I also want to destroy that button and remove any event listeners tied to it. I know the documentation says the `.remove()` will do this for me, but Google Chrome Developer Tools Timeline begs to differ.

By assigning a class for the removal buttons it makes the code a lot cleaner, I used a different approach where I used a global variable to keep track of the number of instances of the removal button, and assigned a unique ID to each new removal button using the instance. Upon clicking the removal button, I could then use `.off()` and `destroy` to remove it. Doing it this way keeps my DOM Node Count and Event Listener Count down, but the code is very messy and I generally dont like to use globals....IS THERE A HAPPY MEDIUM HERE? or am I stuck choosing between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this code from your fiddle and edited it:

```
$(".remove_0").on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    var textInst = instance;
    $(this).unbind('click').remove();                   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s8uXc/2/